# Inno Setup - Not picking up enviroment variables

Tags: process, environment-variables, inno-setup

I'm trying to run an Inno setup from another process, as can be seen below.

```
ProcessStartInfo pstart = new ProcessStartInfo(@"setup.exe");
pstart.UseShellExecute = false;
pstart.EnvironmentVariables.Add("SomeKey", "SomeValue");
Process.Start(pstart);
```

However, [Process] environment variables (environment variables set on the process) don't seem to be picked up. It only seems to pick up [User/Machine] environment variables.

Im using the variable as : {%SomeKey|Fallback}

And when trying to use [Process] environment variables, it always uses the fallback.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inno uses `ShellExecute` in order to relaunch itself with elevated permissions (when `PrivilegesRequired=admin` -- which is the default -- and if the installer is not already running with admin permissions).  As a result of this, the parent process of the "real" installer is the shell, not your application, so it cannot inherit environment variables from it.

You should use command line parameters or a `/loadinf`-style response file instead.

If you desperately want the environment variables to carry through, then you can try launching it with elevated permissions yourself (possibly via a helper app).  However bear in mind that doing this will disable some of the standard functionality, such as `runasoriginaluser` (which is used by default on `postinstall` `[Run]` entries).

Comment: A note to the OP, but the stripping on the environment variables is a deliberate act by the UAC system for security purposes.

Comment: I thought that might be the case too.  Certainly it doesn't make sense for user-level settings (eg. HOMEPATH or USERNAME, or anything the user has set themselves on their own profile) to carry though.  And there's no way for the shell to distinguish them at the process level short of clearing it all and starting over.

Comment: What do you mean by /loadinf?

Comment: One of the command line parameters that you can pass to an Inno installer is [`/LOADINF=filename`](http://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/topic_setupcmdline.htm#LOADINF) which tells it to load settings for the install from an INF file.  By default this only loads the standard page settings, but it is [possible to extend it to custom settings](http://vincenzo.net/isxkb/index.php?title=Remembering_Custom_Page_Settings) if you wish.